# お名前.comで同じELBのDNSを2つ設定するとDNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAINのエラーが発生してしまいました。

Tags: aws, dns

お名前.comで同じELBのDNSを2つ設定するとDNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAINのエラーが発生してしまいました。

【構成】
ELBにACMを設定し、その配下にEC2が一台ぶら下がっているような構成になっております。

```
ELBのDNS 名:
elb名-xxxxxxxxx.ap-northeast-1.elb.amazonaws.com
```

Route53は使用しておらず、
以下のDNS名をそのまま、お名前.comでDNSレコード設定をしております。

お名前.comでDNSレコード設定
https://gyazo.com/7bb869f72e68a6952356f74a0789a4f9

初回リリースはsub1というサブドメインのみの運用でして、
sub1.example.com

のサービスをリリースさせて問題なく、稼働しておりました。

安定稼働していたため、次の改善策として、
サブドメインをわけて、特定のユーザー向けのサービスを展開することになりました。

そのため、sub2というサブドメインをお名前.comで設定した上で、

sub2.example.com

というサービスをリリースさせました。

しかし、その後から、sub2のサブドメインに対して、
DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAINのエラーが発生してしまうようになりました。

あわせて、上記エラーは全ユーザーに対してではなく、一部のユーザー(これまでの問い合わせが来たユーザーの傾向はすべてWindowユーザー)
のみが、エラーが発生しており、全員が見られないわけではありません。

【お名前.comでの設定】

```
sub1.example.com CNAME 3600 elb名-xxxxxxxxx.ap-northeast-1.elb.amazonaws.com
sub2.example.com CNAME 3600 elb名-xxxxxxxxx.ap-northeast-1.elb.amazonaws.com
```

そのため、原因がわからず困っております。

色々と試したり、お名前.comに問い合わせたりしたのですが、
解決できず、何か、ヒントになる情報でもわかりましたら教えていただけないでしょうか？

```
dig CNAME sub2.example.com

; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> CNAME sub2.example.com.
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 33436
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;elb名-xxxxxxxxx.ap-northeast-1.elb.amazonaws.com.   IN  CNAME

;; ANSWER SECTION:
sub2.example.com. 3599  IN  CNAME   elb名-xxxxxxxxx.ap-northeast-1.elb.amazonaws.com.

;; Query time: 110 msec
;; SERVER: xxx.xxx.x.x#53(xxx.xxx.x.x)
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 107
```

何卒宜しくお願いします。

### 追記

B2C向けのサービスなので、可能な限りエンドユーザーに対応を強いたくないのですが、
こういうことをすることで解決する可能性がありますでしょうか？

DNSキャッシュをクリア
http://www.errorcode-search.com/command/Windows10/admin-tool-command/ipconfig-flushdns.html

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/69122

Answer (score 0):

真っ先に思い浮かぶのはブラウザのキャッシュの影響ですが、問題のあるPCで、Chromeの「ゲストモード」で接続出切るようなら、ブラウザのキャッシュクリアをしてみると良いと思います。

---

コメント読んで追記

`DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN` というエラーは クライアント環境の問題のような気がしますので、クライアント環境のブラウザ、OS、ネットワークの各レイヤーでDNS名前解決が正常に行えるかトラブルシューヒングをしてみると何か分かるかもしれません。

ブラウザは既に確認されているようですので、OSレベルでキャッシュクリアしてみるとどうでしょう。ただ、複数のPCで同じ現象なら ネットワーク上のDNSキャッシュしている存在がないか調べてみると良いかもしれません。

わたしの経験上ではユーザ環境のルーターのDNSキャッシュをクリアしたら治ったということがありました。

Comment: 2人、エラーが発生したユーザーに検証に手伝っていただいたのですが、その際に複数のブラウザで検証しましたが、ダメでした。検証の目的はキャッシュ問題なのか、ブラウザ依存の問題なのかを知りたかったのですが、いずれでもありませんでした。